# Can't re-upload packed to Magento Marketplace?

Tags: magento2, marketplace

After i was fixed issues validate my module and re-upload packed to `Magento Marketplace` get

> The "100.1.2" archive version has to be equal or greater than the  "101.0.1" version.

File name `modulename_patch_v100.1.2.zip`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your old package version is `"101.0.1"`, So you have to set new version equal or greater than the `"101.0.1"`. You can set like `"101.0.2"` or any other.

Comment: yep i make it new version is   "version": "100.1.2" in composer.js. but get same issue.

Comment: Set "101.0.2". Version "100.0.2" is lesser than "101.0.1"

Comment: Just a clarification.
The version change should be done in the composer.json